# Bash : Create CSV file from multiple text lists

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have multiple text lists, each representing a column and already in corresponding order.

i.e.

FirstName.txt:

```
Bob  
Sarah  
Fred
```

LastName.txt

```
Smith  
Fulton  
Jones
```

Gender.txt

```
Male  
Female  
Male
```

Age.txt

```
23  
28  
31
```

In BASH, how can I pull the relevant lines together to form a csv formatted entry such as..

```
FirstName,LastName,Gender,Age  
Bob,Smith,Male,23  
Sarah,Fulton,Female,28  
Fred,Jones,Male,31
```

With thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `paste` with comma as delimiter:

```
$ paste -d',' FirstName.txt LastName.txt gender.txt age.txt
Bob,Smith,Male,23
Sarah,Fulton,Female,28
Fred,Jones,Male,31
```

---

From `man paste`:

> **paste** - merge lines of files
>
> **-d, --delimiters=LIST**
>
> reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs

Comment: Perfect! I had no idea paste existed.

Comment: It is pretty handy! As anubhava said, it is perfect for these cases.

Answer (score 5):

That is tailor made job for `paste`:

```
paste -d',' FirstName.txt LastName.txt gender.txt age.txt
Bob,Smith,Male,23
Sarah,Fulton,Female,28
Fred,Jones,Male,31
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick help on this one gents. Paste is my friend.